# ifort fortran library linking issue on Linux

Tags: linux, compilation, fortran, intel

I am having an issue that I believe is the result of compiler versions.  I have three external libraries, we will call liba, libb, and libc.  All of the libraries compiled without any issues using ifort 11.1 on Redhat Linux 5.3.  This is the snippet of code from the makefile, which works just fine:

```
foo.exe: foo.o
    ifort -m64 foo.o liba libb libc -o $@
```

I am trying to move the code to a new system, which is using ifort 16.0.2 on Redhat Linux 6.7.  The makefiles for the external libraries work without any modification.  However, when I go to compile the executable using the same code shown above, I get multiple undefined reference errors.

My guess is that there is an environmental variable I need to modify or a compiler/linker option that I need to add, but I am unsure  where to go from here.

Comment: Are the undefined reference errors relating to symbols in your provided libs or to some other libs?

Comment: Yes, the undefined reference errors are related to the provided libs.

Comment: Are the libraries in the directory in which you're compiling? If not where are they installed?

Comment: The libraries are not built in the same directory, but I have symbolic links to them.

Comment: If you het an error, you must show it. Really, it should be automatic. We need to see the undefined references.

Comment: There is no sin in recompiling the libraries with ifort16...